# Netbeans & PHP; class_alias and code-complete

Tags: php, netbeans, alias, code-completion

Quick one; Netbeans 7.0 for PHP development:

Is there any way to inform NetBeans when `class_alias` has been used to alias a class, thereby triggering code-completion for the alias?

```
class Foo{
    public static $hello = 'world';
}

class_alias('Foo', 'Bar');

Bar::$h // triggers code completion for $hello
       ^
```

I'm still working towards becoming adept with NetBeans, and haven't really played to much with the config, so I'm hoping there's some sort of project specific config I can modify.

Thanks in advance folks.

---

Interestingly, I <strike>can</strike> **can't**<sub>See below</sub> instead use namespacing's `use` (*though my project is otherwise namespace free*) to achieve what NetBeans will understand:

```
class Foo{
    public static $hello = 'world';
}

use \Foo as Bar;

Bar::$h // DOES trigger code completion for $hello
       ^
```

<strike>I don't know if this is a viable solution though. My `Loader` class also holds a map of `alias => classname` and when a given class is auto-loaded, the load method searches the map and aliases if necessary.</strike>

This wouldn't work as hoped, as `use` is completely unsuited to any sort of dynamic aliasing:

- Can't be used in any scope other than global, `use` in a function or method issues a parse error.
- `use` has no support for dynamic naming; `use \{$class} as {$alias};` is illegal.
- **Most importantly**, `use` doesn't carry through file inclusions, thereby rendering it's usage ... well, useless. Pun-tastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, I don't think there is.

I have to say `class_alias` is a new one on me!

Comment: Yea, its quite useful for view generation to keep your helper classnames short. `My_Super_Text_Transformer_Helper` to `TextTrans` is a beautiful thing :)

Answer (score 6):

I managed to create a bit of a workaround for this

In the bootstrap of your project you can create the aliases

```
class_alias('Some\Namespaced\ClassName', 'aliasName');
class_alias('Some\Namespaced\ClassName2', 'anotherAlias');
```

In order to get Netbeans to pick it up you can create a dummy file somewhere in your project.
eg. aliases.php

```
class aliasName extends \Some\Namespaced\ClassName{}
class anotherAlias extends \Some\Namespaced\ClassName2{}
```

Extend is not directly equivalent to class_alias but for code hinting purposes it works fine.

**IMPORTANT!** Do not actually include this file anywhere into your project, the mere presence of this file will allow Netbeans to generate the code hints.